# Auth0: How to know if user was just sign in or sign up? (using loginsCount is a wrong way)

Tags: reactjs, auth0

How to know if user was just sign in or sign up in Auth0?

My case is, when user sign in, I redirect them to page A, but when user sign up, I redirect them to page B (this page is to init their profile)

Well, some people say that I should use ‘loginCount’, if it equal to 1, mean user was just sign up then the app redirect user to page B.

The problem is, suppose user was signed up, and they had complete all steps from page B, now they are in page A as expect, but when user reload the page, the app redirect user to the page B, and they stuck in this page, because the ‘loginCount’ is still equal to 1, it only add up when the user actually sign in using email and password.

Comment: Attach an screen A & B image, So helps to understand your concern